# How do you map a NFS drive location to a subdirectory on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, nfs, subdirectory

How do you map a NFS drive location to a subdirectory on windows 7?

I have a NFS linux location:

`$ mount`

`/nfs on nfs1.wgresorts.com:/nfsdata/export2/dev remote/read/write/setuid/devices/rstchown/rsize=32768/wsize=32768/timeo=14/intr/hard/noac/vers=3/xattr/dev=8c00007 on Mon Mar 17 11:19:45 2014`

I want to map it to C:\nfs\ because I have a webapp that wants the 'nfs' to be mounted directly off the root, and all the file references in the application are to /nfs/whatever/subdirectory/somefile, and I don't want to rewrite or analyze the existing file access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First mount the nfs drive as a drive letter.

```
mount nfs1.wgresorts.com:/nfsdata/export2/dev f:
```

Then link the desired location to that drive letter.

```
mklink /d c:\nfs f:
```